# Customizing RegisterController.php - Laravel 5.3

Tags: controllers, laravel-5.3

I want to restrict the access to the route **/register** to:

```
if(Auth::user()->admin == 1)
```

However, I can't seem to find the **showRegistrationForm()** method in **RegisterController.php** as shown under **Router.php** in *vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing*

Here's my **RegisterController.php**

http://pastebin.com/RVARcy0r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a method `showRegistrationForm()` in your controller. All these methods are defined in the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php`.

Also, restrict the access in the middleware.

Comment: Thanks! These changes have been confusing me.